# Eclipse Scout Form position

Tags: layout, eclipse-scout

I saw scout tutorial of page layout : [DEMO project](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/HowTo/3.8/Open_a_Form_in_a_View)
and in this demo bottom form is from left to right corner of screen.

[image]

But When I try to implement this I get :

[image]

and my bottom form is not the whole length of the screen.

My right form has display view : east
My bottom form has display view : south

central table is AbstractTablePage....

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this either.

The fact is: with SWT you are really free to rearrange the view as you want. You can also organize the class implementing `org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveFactory` (probably `{yourapp}.ui.swt.perspective.Perspective`) as you want. Maybe this was done to obtain the screenshot you have mentioned.

For Swing and RAP there is no Workbench. Scout is providing its implementation of the Main Windows. I am not sure if and how you can influence it.

For RAP, you might have a look at `RwtScoutDesktop` and in particular `RwtScoutDesktop.createViewArea(Composite)`. `ViewArea` seems to be the class that does the mapping between the DisplayViewId defined in the Scout Model and the GUI.